# Flask filename substitution

Tags: python, html, templates, flask

I am a bit lost with this error on Flask. I have a directory structure like this:

```
 Project/
   static/
   templates/index.html
   main.py
```

In main.py I have an end point like this:

```
@app.route('/summary/<string:customer>')
def show_summary(customer='all'):
   # Do bunch of computation, generate customer.csv
   return render_template("index.html", fn="customer_xxx.csv")
```

In my index.html in templates I have:

```
var f={{fn}};
d3.csv(f, type, function(error, test) {
```

But when I run it, the csv file never gets recognized. When I look at the browser debugger, I am seeing:

```
var f=customer_xxx.csv;
```

Note that this line gives an error as the quotes are missing. What am I doing wrong? How do I get it to properly recognize this file? I know that it works when I hardcode it in my index.html like this without using Flask:

```
d3.csv("customer_xxx.csv", ..)
```

A bit lost...

Comment: you need quotes  `" "` in `var f = "{{fn}}";` to get `var f = "customer_xxx.csv";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need quotes `" "` in

```
var f = "{{fn}}";
```

to get result similar to

```
var f = "customer_xxx.csv";
```